# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'quantity') at

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I receive all the data but adding to cart does not work, for some reason it complains about the quantity. Ultimately I want to make a shopping cart that works with cookies and firebase. Can you tell me where I went wrong? P.S. I apologize for my English, if something is not clear, ask

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Тестовая страница</h1>
            <div class="iconCart">
                <img src="/icons/icon.png">
                <div class="totalQuantity">0</div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="listProduct">

            <div class="item">
                <img src="" alt="">
                <h2>Что то / Черный / Автоматик</h2>
                <div class="price">$550</div>
                <button>Добавить в корзину</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart">
        <h2>
            Корзина
        </h2>

        <div class="listCart">


            <div class="item">
                <img src="">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="name">Что то / Черный / Автоматик</div>
                    <div class="price">$550 / 1 товар</div>
                </div>
                <div class="quantity">
                    <button>-</button>
                    <span class="value">3</span>
                    <button>+</button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="close">
                Закрыть
            </div>
            <div class="checkout">
                <a href="checkout.html">Оформить</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/7.14.1-0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

For security, I hid the config but rest assured it is here

index.js

```
firebase.initializeApp(config2);
 window.onload=function(){

    this.addDataToHTML();
}


let iconCart = document.querySelector('.iconCart');
let cart = document.querySelector('.cart');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let close = document.querySelector('.close');

iconCart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(cart.style.right == '-100%'){
        cart.style.right = '0';
        container.style.transform = 'translateX(-400px)';
    }else{
        cart.style.right = '-100%';
        container.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    }
})
close.addEventListener('click', function (){
    cart.style.right = '-100%';
    container.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
})




//show datas product in list 
function addDataToHTML(){
    // remove datas default from HTML
    firebase.database().ref('Products/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    let listProductHTML = document.querySelector('.listProduct');
    listProductHTML.innerHTML = '';
    var data=snapshot.val();
    // add new datas
    if(data != null) // if has data
    {
        for(let[key,value] of Object.entries(data)){
            let newProduct = document.createElement('div');
            newProduct.classList.add('item');
            newProduct.innerHTML = 
            `<img src="${value.image}" alt="">
            <h2>${value.pname}</h2>
            <div class="price">$${value.price}</div>
            <button onclick="addCart(${value.pid})">Добавить в корзину</button>`;

            listProductHTML.appendChild(newProduct);
        }
        
    }
});

}


let listCart = [];
function checkCart(){
    var cookieValue = document.cookie
    .split('; ')
    .find(row => row.startsWith('listCart='));
    if(cookieValue){
        listCart = JSON.parse(cookieValue.split('=')[1]);
    }else{
        listCart = [];
    }
}
checkCart();
function addCart($idProduct){
    firebase.database().ref('Products/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
       

    let productsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
    //// If this product is not in the cart
    if(!listCart[$idProduct]) 
    {
        var value=snapshot.val();


        listCart[$idProduct] = productsCopy.filter(value => value.pid == $idProduct)[0];
        listCart[$idProduct].quantity = 1;
        console.log(listCart[$idProduct]);


    }else{
        //If this product is already in the cart.
        //I just increased the quantity
        listCart[$idProduct].quantity++;
    }
    document.cookie = "listCart=" + JSON.stringify(listCart) + "; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2025 23:59:59 UTC; path=/;";

    addCartToHTML();

});

}
addCartToHTML();
function addCartToHTML(){
    firebase.database().ref('Products/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){

    // clear data default
    let listCartHTML = document.querySelector('.listCart');
    listCartHTML.innerHTML = '';
    var products=snapshot.val();

    let totalHTML = document.querySelector('.totalQuantity');
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    // if has product in Cart
    if(listCart){
        for(let[key,value] of Object.entries(products)){
            if(value){
                let newCart = document.createElement('div');
                newCart.classList.add('item');
                newCart.innerHTML = 
                    `<img src="${value.image}">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="name">${value.pname}</div>
                        <div class="price">$${value.price} / 1 товар</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <button onclick="changeQuantity(${value.pid}, '-')">-</button>
                        <span class="value">${value.quantity}</span>
                        <button onclick="changeQuantity(${value.pid}, '+')">+</button>
                    </div>`;
                listCartHTML.appendChild(newCart);
            } 
                totalQuantity = totalQuantity + value.quantity;

             


            }
                
                    }
    totalHTML.innerText = totalQuantity;
});

}
function changeQuantity($idProduct, $type){
    firebase.database().ref('Products/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){

    switch ($type) {
        case '+':
            listCart[$idProduct].quantity++;
            break;
        case '-':
            listCart[$idProduct].quantity--;

            // if quantity <= 0 then remove product in cart
            if(listCart[$idProduct].quantity <= 0){
                delete listCart[$idProduct];
            }
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
    // save new data in cookie
    document.cookie = "listCart=" + JSON.stringify(listCart) + "; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2025 23:59:59 UTC; path=/;";
    // reload html view cart
    addCartToHTML();
});
}
```

Comment: so either `listCart[$idProduct]` or `value` is null somewhere. console.log() can point you to where it is.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I checked null for this quantity, but it still doesn’t occur to me how this can be fixed

Comment: Hard to guess.... what line does the error message point to?

Comment: @epascarello Swears at "listCart[$idProduct] = productsCopy.filter(value => value.pid == $idProduct)[0];" & "totalQuantity = totalQuantity + value.quantity;" &           "listCart[$idProduct].quantity++;" & "listCart[$idProduct].quantity--;"